# What to upgrade first from an ancient system

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, processor

It's my birthday coming up and I'm hoping for some money to put towards my gaming pc build.
The parts of the build that are important to my question are:
i5 2500 + any eBay 1155 mobo
8gb ddr3 (4gb now an extra 4gb later)
GTX 1050ti 4gb

Right now I'm on a Pentium D (one of the higher clocked ones not that it matters) and a quadro fx1700 (modern Intel HD are better) with 4gb ram.

So my question is this, the CPU and mobo with a new PSU and 4gb ram would be £150 roughly (I have a case and hard drive) and the 1050ti would be the same price. Would I get more performance gain by getting everything but the GPU now or by putting the GPU with my Pentium D? Eventually I'll have the i5 paired with the 1050ti but I can't afford it all at once.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd upgrade the CPU and mainboard.

If you were doing workstation graphics work, the i5-2500's onboard graphics would be a substantial downgrade from your Quadro.  But the same optimizations that make the Quadro a powerful workstation card make it a poor choice for a gaming card -- even though the HD 2000 has fewer compute cores and shares its RAM with the system, it'll be faster for games than the Quadro.

Comment: Sorry my bad for not phrasing the question well, it's for gaming, I use the old quadro because it's what I have, would the i5s igpu be better at gaming? Sorry my fault, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: For gaming, yes, the i5 will be better.  If you were trying to render huge pointclouds from a scientific dataset, or needed high color accuracy while creating a movie, the Quadro would be better.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll go with the CPU and mobo and get the 1050 when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You should be thinking long-term here.  In your cirumstances it's generally better to put your money into a new motherboard/CPU first (video card abilities evolve much faster than motherboard slots change).  But YMMV.
There's a "trap" if you replace the video card first: When you get around to replacing the motherboard you could end up wanting to (or have to) upgrade the video card at the same time.  Not to mention that buying the video card first prevents you from profiting from any video card advances (or price decreases) in the meantime.

Comment: Whichever I don't get now I'll get at Christmas so it's litteraly just about which to buy first to get the most performance before I fully upgrade.